# What is the correct way to call IBAction from different controller?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-2.0

It's about objective c and cocoa

I've faced a problem and don't know how to solve it. Hope I can find answer here and it will be helpful for some other programmers.

So, I have a simple window with 4 elements:

1. NSTextField - first field to set value
2. NSButton - to set value in first field
3. NSTextField - second field to set value
4. NSButton - to set value in second field

here is "controller 1" code:

```
#import "controller2.h"

@interface controller1 : NSControl{
IBOutlet NSTextField * text1;
}
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation controller1
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
[text1 setStringValue:@"text1 changed"];

// create controller 2 instance
controller2 * c2 = [[[controller2 alloc] init] autorelease];
// call first time using one way
[c2 click:self];

// call second time using another way
[self sendAction:@selector(click:) to:c2];
}
@end
```

and controller 2 code:

```
@interface controller2 : NSControl{
IBOutlet NSTextField * text2;
}
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation controller2
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
[text2 setStringValue:@"text 2 changed"];
NSLog(@"Test2");
}
@end
```

when I click on button1 I rase "click" in controller1 - everything is fine and work correct

when I click on button2 I rase "click" in controller2 - everything is fine and work correct

BUT if I want to click button1 and rase "click" in controller2 it doesn't work (

Can anyone help with it? It seems to have a very simple resolution but i don't know what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
controller2 * c2 = [[[controller2 alloc] init] autorelease];
```

You're creating a completely new "controller2" (bad name for a class, by the way - always capitalize class names: "MyController", etc.). You need an IBOutlet from your Controller1 to a Controller2. That way you can send messages to it by name.

Remember: objects in a nib are "freeze-dried" **instances** of classes.

Comment: Yes I think you're right about creating completely new "controller2". But what type of IBOutlet should I write in controller1? It is impossible to create something like this "IBOutlet IBAction * click;".

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run before you can walk with Cocoa development. The format is "IBOutlet ClassName * outletName;" In your case, use whatever your "controller2" class name is. Alternatively, you can use "IBOutlet id outletName" for "just any old object", but using a specific class is best as it helps eliminate errors (and lets Interface Builder filter out inappropriate connections when you try to establish them).

Comment: (Re)Read this page *thoroughly* - it clarifies the problems you're struggling with. One of the first sections (titled "Outlets") answers the question in your comment directly: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html